# Как поставить множество аргументов в цикл while?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть цикл while. Когда пользователь на вопрос "Хочешь научу тебя рисовать?" печатает "да","давай","хочу","конечно" должно печататься "Здорово! Какой цвет выберешь?". Допустим пользователь много раз вводит рандомные слова вместо перечисленных. Программа кружится в цикле. Потом вводит слово "да" и программа в этом случае работает. Когда вводит остальные перечисленные слова программа просто так же остается в цикле. Как сделать так, чтобы программа видела и остальные варианты после завершения цикла? Ну или как вообще использовать несколько аргументов в одном цикле? Пример цикла while a != b "да" or "давай" у меня не заработал

```
from turtle import*
print("Привет!")
print("Давай познакомимся :smile:")
name = input("Меня зовут Бот, а тебя?")
print("Очень приятно, " + name)
question = input("хочешь я тебя научу рисовать?")
if question == "да":
    col = input("Здорово! Какой цвет выберешь?")
    if col == "красный":
        color("red")
else:
    if question == "давай":
        col = input("Здорово! Какой цвет выберешь?")
        if col == "красный":
            color("red")
    elif question == "хочу":
        col = input("Здорово! Какой цвет выберешь?")
        if col == "красный":
            color("red")
    elif question == "конечно":
        col = input("Здорово! Какой цвет выберешь?")
        if col == "красный":
            color("red")
while question != "да":
    print("Подумай еще!")
    question = input("хочешь я тебя научу рисовать?")
while question != "давай":
    print("Подумай еще!")
    question = input("хочешь я тебя научу рисовать?")
col = input("Здорово! Какой цвет выберешь?")
if col == "красный":
    color("red")
t = input("Цвет выбран! Что будем рисовать?")
```

Answer (score 2):

Условия `question != "да"` и `question != "давай"` нужно через `и` описывать:

```
while question != "да" and question != "давай":
    print("Подумай еще!")
    question = input("хочешь я тебя научу рисовать?")
```

Еще можно через оператор `not in`:

```
while question not in ("да", "давай"):
    print("Подумай еще!")
    question = input("хочешь я тебя научу рисовать?")
```

Т.е. если значение `question` не совпадает с теми, что в скобках

Answer (score 1):

Тоже пока на стадии изучения Python, но я бы Вашу программу написал так:

```
start_paint_words = ['да', 'давай', 'хочу', 'конечно']

# каждый охотник желает знать где сидит фазан
paint_colors = [
    'красный',
    'оранжевый',
    'желтый',
    'зеленый',
    'голубой',
    'синий',
    'фиолетовый'
]

print('Привет!')
print("Давай познакомимся :smile:")
user_name = input("Меня зовут Бот, а тебя?\n> ")
print(f'Очень приятно, {user_name}')

while input('Хочешь я тебя научу рисовать?\n> ') not in start_paint_words:
    print("Подумай еще!")

color_for_paint = input('Здорово! Выбери цвет из палитры КОЖЗГСФ\n> ')
while color_for_paint not in paint_colors:
    color_for_paint = input('Такого цвета я не знаю, выберете цвет из палитры КОЖЗГСФ\n> ')

print(f'Здорово! Ты выбрал цвет {color_for_paint}, что будем рисовать?')
paint_figure = input('> ')
```

Comment: Для определения входит ли X во множество N рекомендуют использовать сет, а не список. Это быстрее. На малом количестве элементов без разницы, конечно.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо, учту в будущем.